# select columns from multiple tables with join

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables:-

`users (username, business_id, etc.)`

`businesses (business_id, service_type, latitude, longitude, etc.)`

And I have the following query which works fine:

```
SELECT username, users.business_id FROM users JOIN businesses 
ON users.business_id = businesses.business_id WHERE service_type = ?
```

Now, I want to also have in the results the columns '**latitude**' and '**longitude**' in '**businesses**' table. How can I do that?

I tried to do the following but I get an error:

```
SELECT username, users.business_id, businesses.latitude, businesses.longitude 
FROM users, businesses JOIN businesses 
ON users.business_id = businesses.business_id WHERE service_type = ?
```

What is the right way to get the results I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use explicit join syntax:

```
SELECT username, users.business_id, 
       businesses.latitude, businesses.longitude 
FROM users 
JOIN businesses 
   ON users.business_id = businesses.business_id 
WHERE service_type = ?
```

You are mixing implicit with explicit syntax. So `, businesses` that is used in the `FROM` clause, is actually not necessary.

Comment: I did as you suggested. This doesn't produce an error but it doesn't get the latitude and longitude values from the database. The result set returns '0' value for each of those columns...

Comment: @ElyakimLevi Can you post some sample data that help elucidate the issue?

Comment: Ahh this is my fault. Had one row in the database which actually had 0 values.. Thanks for the help. I'll mark this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

you have businesses twice in the where part:

```
FROM users, businesses JOIN businesses
```

remove the first one, should be like before:

```
FROM users JOIN businesses
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo with `JOIN` syntax, try the following:

```
SELECT users.username, users.business_id, businesses.latitude, businesses.longitude 
FROM users JOIN businesses ON users.business_id = businesses.business_id 
WHERE service_type = ?
```